# How to update reference column in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, migration

I have a migration that I want to make with a reference in my table. I create the reference using this:

```
create_table :user_events do |t|
  t.references :user, :null => false
end
```

And in my migration, I want to be able to allow the reference to be NULL.

```
def self.up
  change_column :user_events, :user, :integer, :null => true
end
```

However I keep getting `PGError: ERROR:  column "user" of relation "user_events" does not exist`. Am I migrating wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
def self.up
  change_column :user_events, :user_id, :integer, :null => true
end
```

Note that the column you're trying to change is called `user_id`, not `user`

Answer (score 1):

It's because your migration creates a column named user_id, referencing the User model.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
def self.up
  change_column :user_events do |c|
    c.references :user, :integer, :null => true  
  end 
end
```